# Python and AutoHotKey script does not work after compiling to exe (pyinstaller)

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, autohotkey

[image]

I have a simple AHK script in Python via "ahk 0.12.0" library (pypi).

After using pyinstaller to make executable, executable
quits giving me "window/get.ahk" exception.

Has anybody encountered this before or know how to solve?

```
from ahk import AHK
import time


ahk = AHK(executable_path='C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\AutoHotkey.exe')

win = ahk.win_get(title='AnyDesk')
win.maximize()
ahk.mouse_move(100, 440, speed=1)
ahk.double_click()
time.sleep(3)
ahk.send_input(xyz)
ahk.key_press(key='Enter')
time.sleep(3)
ahk.mouse_move(100, 10, speed=15)
ahk.double_click()
```

Project tree

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['optiplex_log.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Robert\\Desktop\\python\\ahk_python'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='optiplex_log',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

Comment: Quite impossible to say what's wrong based off the info you've given. At least show your scripts and screenshot the error.

Comment: Solution found!  `[--add-data <SRC;DEST or SRC:DEST>]` so `--add-data C:\*\*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\ahk";"ahk"`